# Triggering :active state html label element

Tags: html, css, label

I've been passed a recently-appeared bug which involves a label element nolonger being set to :active.

My (probably) simple question is: How would I toggle the label's :active state when the label is clicked? I can check dev tools and test what the css will do if the label **were** :active (see screenshot below) but how would I get the label to actually be :active? The :hover state works, so I'm hoping :active can too.

This had previously been working, apparently and, as you can see from the screenshot, the css for an :active state had already been written.

Just to be clear: I don't want to add an 'active' class to the element; I want to exploit the in-build :active state, similar to :hover.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to make your input activated while clicking on the label?

Comment: Plenty of questions like this already on here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388102/can-you-style-an-active-form-inputs-label-with-just-css or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859542/toggling-styles-on-label-active-focus-for-input-field-with-css-only

Comment: The difference with my question is the input element is inside the label element. I'm reluctant to change the markup as this will affect other functionality.

Comment: @Saurav: I want to set the label's :active state. I'm not sure if that's the question you're asking...

Comment: @Saurav: Just to clarify; I want to toggle the label's :active state by clicking on the label (which has the classes 'btn' and 'btn-primary').

Answer (score -1):

there is no active or selected state for label element.
What you see is a bootsrap trick imo
You are free to give any class to get it worked, e.g.

```js
 $('.u').on('click', function(){
            $('.u').removeClass('e');
            $(this).addClass('e');
        });
```

```css
 .u:focus {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .u {
                background-color: lightgrey;
            }
            .e {
                background-color:  red;
            }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">

                                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                <label class="btn btn-md u e" >
                                                    <input type="radio" name="weight" value="1">Small (0-3 lbs)
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="btn btn-md u">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="weight" value="2"> Medium (3-7 lbs)
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="btn btn-md u">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="weight" value="3"> Large (7+ lbs)
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```